# Nodejs convert windows-1252 to utf-8 in express

Tags: node.js, express, windows-1252

My Express server cannot handle requests with the windows-1252 character set because Express router puts the path in the `decodeURIComponent()` method and throws an error. My idea now is to call the `decodeURIComponent()` method myself in a middleware, catch the error and then try to work with a replacement. I have already found a corresponding table in section *ASCII Encoding Reference* in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

My first question is, is this possible?
My second question is, is there a package for this? I have to rely on `require` statements, I can't include packages with `import`.

An example path
`/pictures/M%F6bel.png`
should convert to `/pictures/M%C3%B6bel.png` so that the rest of the express logic can remain untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of client would send an invalid URL like `/pictures/M%F6bel.png`? Anyway:

```js
var path = "/pictures/M%F6bel.png"
  .replace(/%u(....)/g, (m,p)=>String.fromCharCode("0x"+p))
  .replace(/%(..)/g, (m,p)=>String.fromCharCode("0x"+p))
```

and `encodeURI(path)` then gives the percent-encoded version à la utf-8.

This allows you to write a middleware like

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    decodeURI(req.url);
  } catch(e) {
    if (e.message === "URI malformed")
      req.url = encodeURI(req.url
        .replace(/%u(....)/g, (m,p)=>String.fromCharCode("0x"+p))
        .replace(/%(..)/g, (m,p)=>String.fromCharCode("0x"+p)));
  }
  next();
});
```

Note that changing `req.url` in this way automatically changes `req.path` as well. By contrast, `req.originalUrl` remains unchanged (as its name might suggest).

This does not work on characters that are defined in Windows-1252 but not in Unicode (like the range 0x80-0x9F). Such characters are not allowed in URLs.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really smart approach. Now I just have to figure out where exactly I have to replace the path in Express before Express itself starts decoding.

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: This does fail on characters that are defined in Windows-1252 but not in Unicode (like the range 0x80-0x9F).

Comment: @robertklep do you have a better suggestion or a bulletproof?

Comment: @user1791139 you can use a module like [`windows-1252`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1252) and use its `decode` function in addition  to the regular expression (`decode(req.url.replace(…))`).